# Errors 1005 and 150 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `languages` (
  `language_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `language_abbrv` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `language_english` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `language_local` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`language_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `language_id_UNIQUE` (`language_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `language_abbrv_UNIQUE` (`language_abbrv`),
  UNIQUE KEY `language_name_UNIQUE` (`language_english`),
  UNIQUE KEY `language_local_UNIQUE` (`language_local`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `layouts` (
  `layout_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `platform_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `language_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `layout_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`layout_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `layout_id_UNIQUE` (`layout_id`),
  KEY `idx_layouts_platform_id` (`platform_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_layouts_platform_id` FOREIGN KEY (`platform_id`) REFERENCES `platforms` (`platform_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I try to create a foreign key on "layouts" referencing "languages" on the column "language_id", I keep getting an "ERROR 1005: Can't create table  (errno: 150)" error. I don't see where the problem is, and the error doesn't tell me much. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please share your `platform` table create script

Comment: *When I try to create a foreign key on "layouts" referencing "languages" on the column "language_id"*: your script does not actually tries to do that. Please show us your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to create a foreign key on "layouts" referencing "languages" on the column "language_id", I keep getting an [...] error.

To start with: the script that you showed us does not actually tries to create that foreign key.

But anyway: if it was, then it would fail because your tables use a different MySQL engine:  `languages` uses `MyISAM`, while `layouts` uses `InnoDB`. Both tables must use the same engine for the foreign key to be created.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4cb0b312324d9180d91bbfe0154a0515)** (you can change the engine of the first table back to `MyISAM` to generate the error).

**[Documentation reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)**:

> Parent and child tables must use the same storage engine, and they cannot be defined as temporary tables.

Comment: MySQL Workbench keeps using MyISAM by default when creating new tables. I will have to research how to stop this.

Comment: @posfan12: as a workaround you can explictly specify which engine you want to use when creating the table.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition with GMB's answer, if you are trying to create foreign key of your language_id, add this script.

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_layouts_language_id` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `languages` (`language_id`) ON       DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```

Assuming you already created your `platform` table `(same engine=InnoDb)`, you can use below script.

```
CREATE TABLE `layouts` (
  `layout_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `platform_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `language_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `layout_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`layout_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `layout_id_UNIQUE` (`layout_id`),
  KEY `idx_layouts_platform_id` (`platform_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_layouts_language_id` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `languages` (`language_id`) ON         DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_layouts_platform_id` FOREIGN KEY (`platform_id`) REFERENCES `platforms` (`platform_id`) ON         DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=gNbQw95iUR).